# Powershell - How to exclude specific email addresses and domain from output?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to get an output on some remote mailboxes, but need to exclude anyone from that output with an email alias starting with "v0" or "z0" AND a specific email domain.  I try this, but it doesn't appear to work.

Get-RemoteMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {(EmailAddresses -notlike 'smtp:z0*') -or (EmailAddresses -notlike 'smtp:v0*') -and (EmailAddresses -like 'smtp:*@domain.com')}

Comment: Change your `-or` to `-and`

Comment: Get-RemoteMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {(EmailAddresses -notlike 'smtp:z0*') -and (EmailAddresses -notlike 'smtp:v0*') -and (EmailAddresses -like 'smtp:*@domain.com')}                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                   That didn't work. I still have accounts with a "z1" & "v1" in it, and those don't even show on the output.

Comment: `-Filter` should be a **string**, not a scriptblock. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-remotemailbox?view=exchange-ps#parameters)